# write to xml file from list python

Tags: python, xml

I have the following list: '`[TW', 6.5, 'TS', 5.0, 'core_h', 2.0, 'core_tand', 2.0, 'core_er', 2.0, 'trace_height', 5.0, 'trace_er', 5.0, 'trace_tand', 5.0, 'D', 5.0, 'prepreg_h', 14.0, 'prepreg_er', 14.0, 'prepreg_tand', 14.0, 'roughness_level', 22.0]`

Is there a way I can convert it into a string and write it in a filename.xml form
where filename is these valriables along with their values?

They can be seperated b an underscore if comma isnt allowed

Comment: `",".join(YourList)`  or `"_".join(YourList)`?

Comment: That adds a comma between every character of each element.

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: Of the form `variablename1_<value>-variablename2_<val>-....-variablename_N_<value>.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` with list slicing.

**Ex:**

```
s = ['TW', 6.5, 'TS', 5.0, 'core_h', 2.0, 'core_tand', 2.0, 'core_er', 2.0, 'trace_height', 5.0, 'trace_er', 5.0, 'trace_tand', 5.0, 'D', 5.0, 'prepreg_h', 14.0, 'prepreg_er', 14.0, 'prepreg_tand', 14.0, 'roughness_level', 22.0]
res = ""
for i,v in zip(s[::2], s[1::2]):
    res += "{0}_{1}-".format(i, v)

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
TW_6.5TS_5.0core_h_2.0core_tand_2.0core_er_2.0trace_height_5.0trace_er_5.0trace_tand_5.0D_5.0prepreg_h_14.0prepreg_er_14.0prepreg_tand_14.0roughness_level_22.0
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your question it is not so clear. If I get what you meant with you will be okay:

t

```
his_list = ['TW', 6.5, 'TS', 5.0, 'core_h', 2.0, 'core_tand', 2.0, 'core_er', 2.0, 'trace_height', 5.0, 'trace_er', 5.0, 'trace_tand', 5.0, 'D', 5.0, 'prepreg_h', 14.0, 'prepreg_er', 14.0, 'prepreg_tand', 14.0, 'roughness_level', 22.0]

my_string = ""
for _ in this_list :
    my_string += str(_)
```